# Getting an error every time i try to convert my Gnuplot into a log scaled plot

Tags: gnuplot

I've been trying to translate my plot into a log scaled plot but keep getting these errors:

> C:\Users\netha\Technion\Mahmood Jabareen - Nethanel Benzaquen\Thesis\Chapters\Figures\Chapter04\Chapter04_old\Figa>latex
> FigPS.tex This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (MiKTeX
> 21.8) entering extended mode (FigPS.tex LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1 L3 programming layer <2021-07-12>
> (C:\Users\netha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
> Document Class: article 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
> (C:\Users\netha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))
> (C:\Users\netha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
> (C:\Users\netha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty)
> (C:\Users\netha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
> (C:\Users\netha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty)
> (C:\Users\netha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.c
> fg)
> (C:\Users\netha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\dvips.def)
> ))
> (C:\Users\netha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/xcolor\xcolor.sty
> (C:\Users\netha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\color.cfg)
> ) (labelfig.sty (labelfig.tex))
> (C:\Users\netha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty)
> (C:\Users\netha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-dvi
> ps.def) (FigPS.aux) (Pic.tex
> (C:\Users\netha\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\cp1252.def)
> <Pic.eps> ! Number too big.  -2147483648
>
> l.107     \gplfronttext
>
> ? ! Dimension too large.  \unitlength
>
> l.107     \gplfronttext
>
> ? ! Dimension too large.  \unitlength
>
> l.107     \gplfronttext
>
> ? ) [1] (FigPS.aux) ) Output written on FigPS.dvi (1 page, 852 bytes).
> Transcript written on FigPS.log.
>
> C:\Users\netha\Technion\Mahmood Jabareen - Nethanel
> Benzaquen\Thesis\Chapters\Figures\Chapter04\Chapter04_old\Figa>dvips
> -o FigPS.ps  FigPS.dvi This is dvips(k) 2020.1 (MiKTeX21.8)  Copyright 2021 Radical Eye Software ([www.radicaleye.com](http://www.radicaleye.com)) ' TeX output
> 2022.08.05:1116' -> FigPS.ps <C:/Users/netha/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/dvips/base/tex.pro>
> <C:/Users/netha/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/dvips/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.pro>
> <C:/Users/netha/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/dvips/base/texps.pro>
> <C:/Users/netha/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/dvips/base/special.pro>
> <C:/Users/netha/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/dvips/base/color.pro>.
> <C:/Users/netha/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr7.pfb>
> <C:/Users/netha/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi8.pfb>
> <C:/Users/netha/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.pfb>
> [1<./Pic.eps>]
>
> C:\Users\netha\Technion\Mahmood Jabareen - Nethanel
> Benzaquen\Thesis\Chapters\Figures\Chapter04\Chapter04_old\Figa>ps2epsi
> FigPS.ps Fig.eps Error: /limitcheck in --arc-- Operand stack:
> --nostringval--   2646   2147483428   2646   2147483428   23.625   0   360 Execution stack:    %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--
> --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   2015   1   3   %oparray_pop   2014   1   3
> %oparray_pop   1998   1   3   %oparray_pop   1884   1   3
> %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2
> --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval-- Dictionary stack:
> --dict:979/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:110/200(L)--   --dict:179/300(L)--   --dict:45/200(L)--   --dict:190/256(L)-- Current allocation mode is local Current file position is 86494 Error:
> /limitcheck in --arc-- Operand stack:    --nostringval--   2646
> 2147483428   2646   2147483428   23.625   0   360 Execution stack:
> %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
> --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   2015   1   3   %oparray_pop   2014   1   3   %oparray_pop   1998   1   3
> %oparray_pop   1884   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--
> %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
> --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval-- Dictionary stack:
> --dict:982/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:87/200(L)--   --dict:50/50(L)--   --dict:179/300(L)--   --dict:45/200(L)--   --dict:190/256(L)-- Current allocation mode is local MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.25: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Here is a copy of the code I'm running

```
set terminal epslatex
set output 'Pic.tex'

set lmargin 1
set rmargin 1
set bmargin 1
set tmargin 1

set size 0.45,0.50
set pointsize 0.75

set xrange [0.10:+550]
set yrange [0.10:1.000]

set log x
set log y
set ytics nolog

set xlabel "DOF"
#set format x "%4.0f"
set xtics border out scale 1,0.5 nomirror
#set mxtics 5

set ylabel "Error [\\%]" offset 1.0,0
#set format y "%3.2f"
set ytics border out scale 1,0.5 nomirror
#set mytics 4

set tics out
set key at 500,-2.750

#set grid
plot "IGAdisx.txt"  using 1:2 title "\\scriptsize{IGA}"  with linespoints dashtype 1 linewidth 4.000 pointtype 4 linecolor rgb 'blue',\
     "FEAdisx.txt"  using 1:2 title "\\scriptsize{FEA}"  with linespoints dashtype 1 linewidth 4.000 pointtype 6 linecolor rgb 'red'

unset output
```

With the following data:
FEAdisx

42  -13.10825586
130 -3.571865827
266 -1.027164519
450 -0.409075656
682 -0.165172485
962 -0.042107887

IGAdisx

80  -6.514226074
120 -3.369717311
168 -1.761173369
224 -0.97168048
288 -0.551561334
360 -0.310583989
440 -0.162186678
528 -0.065674441
624 0

Answer (score 0):

This may be the same issue as reported on the gnuplot issue tracker: https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/2456/

If so, it is due to a weird compiler error specific to Windows 10 and reported only for the gnuplot epslatex terminal.  Other terminals and other Windows versions are not affected.  Possible work-around: use `set term cairolatex eps` terminal instead of `set term epslatex`.

If you are not using epslatex + Windows 10, please add relevant version and OS information to the question.